# Can I search through 'oldfiles' with a specific name or extension?

Tags: vimscript, command-line, filesystem

I use the `oldfiles` and `browse oldfiles` commands all the time. I find them extremely useful, because it's easier to hit my leader mapping, scan through the files really quickly, and hit

```
q<number><enter>
```

rather than typing out a really long directory path to a specific file. (Especially since sometimes I don't remember which directory it's in)

However, there's only one downside. Since I use vim so frequently, sometimes the file I'm looking for is dozens and dozens of rows down, so it takes a really long time to find. Is there any way I could filter the list of files given by `oldfiles` to show only a certain extension?

For example, a command like:

```
browse oldfiles *.py
```

that shows a list of `.py` files I've recently opened, prompts for a number, and then opens that file.

If there's no way to do this, are there plugins with similar functionality?

Comment: You could use the ``:CtrlPMRU`` command of [CtrlP](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim) with fuzzy search but that might be somewhat different from you're looking for.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Assuming you have Vim 8 you can use `:filter`

```
:browse filter /pattern/ oldfiles
```

For more help see:

```
:h :browse
:h :filter
:h oldfiles
:h new-items-8
```

Comment: Fantastic! That is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: `:h cmd_name` is another gem we didn't expect to get, but is super good to know.  "The hero we needed, but not the one we asked for"

Answer (score 1):

```
:filter /pattern/ oldfiles
```

returns a list of `oldfiles` matching the pattern, indexed, and waits for a command, then enter:

```
:e #<...
```

replace `...` with the wanted file index.